# good old could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I know this is all over SO but i'm still unable to figure it out.

I ran into this exception (could not initialize proxy - no Session) when jackson tries to json-size my classes, googled it, found the famous OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter solution, added it but nothing happens.

Here is my web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Propspace API</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!--      <context-param> -->
<!--         <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name> -->
<!--         <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value> -->
<!--     </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml
                    /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>entityManagerFactoryRead</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


<!--    <listener> -->
<!--        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class> -->
<!--    </listener> -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

And here is my servlet config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">

    <!-- <import resource="mongodb-context.xml" /> -->
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.propspace.api.mongo, com.propspace.api.controller, com.propspace.api.core.service, com.propspace.api.repository, com.propspace.api.helper">
        <!-- <context:include-filter type="aspectj" -->
        <!-- expression="com.propspace.api.mongo" /> -->
    </context:component-scan>



    <!-- Persistence config -->


    <!-- Read related beans -->

    <bean id="permissionsAspect" class="com.propspace.api.aspect.PermissionsAspect" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryRead"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:config/persistence-demo.xml" 
            /> -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="read" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRead" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.propspace.api.*" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceRead" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${JPA.read.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${JPA.read.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${JPA.read.jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="5" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1" />
        <property name="poolName" value="null" />
    </bean>



    <!-- Write related beans -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" 
            /> -->
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="write" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.propspace.api.*" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="jpaProperties"> <props> <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> 
            </props> </property> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${JPA.write.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${JPA.write.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${JPA.write.jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="5" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1" />
        <property name="poolName" value="null" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Sets up our transaction manager. -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> -->
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    </bean>

    <!-- End of write related beans -->


    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="defaultPersistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" factory-bean="entityManagerFactory"
        factory-method="getSessionFactory" />


    <!-- <bean -->
    <!-- class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" 
        /> -->

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.propspace.api.repository" />

    <!-- Defines our transaction manager for Transactional annotations. -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />



    <!-- end of persistence config -->


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/*" />
            <bean name="openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory">
                    <ref bean="entityManagerFactoryRead"></ref>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>



    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="requireSession" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <!-- Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, 
        but for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, 
        so we must define an explicit mapping for it. -->
    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"></bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- The index controller. -->
    <bean name="indexController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
        <property name="viewName" value="index" />
    </bean>


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="permissions" class="com.propspace.api.aspect.PermissionsAspect" />

    <!-- Customized type conversion of error Messages - Message Bundle -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n/application" />
    </bean>






    <!-- Cache -->
    <!-- <cache:annotation-driven /> -->

    <!-- Ehcache annotation config -->
    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />

    <!-- <ehcache:config cache-manager="ehCacheManager"> <ehcache:evict-expired-elements 
        interval="60" /> </ehcache:config> -->

    <bean id="ehCacheManager"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="shared">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

And finally here is the full trace:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.propspace.api.core.domain.Contacts.landlordListings, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:500)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
        at com.propspace.api.helper.BaseDomainSerializer.serializeMapObjects(BaseDomainSerializer.java:196)
        at com.propspace.api.helper.BaseDomainSerializer.passToSerialize(BaseDomainSerializer.java:175)
        at com.propspace.api.helper.BaseDomainSerializer.serialize(BaseDomainSerializer.java:268)
        at com.propspace.api.helper.BaseDomainSerializer.serialize(BaseDomainSerializer.java:31)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:273)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$AsArraySerializer.serialize(ContainerSerializers.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:587)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:245)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1145)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:203)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)

        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1024)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```